# Dropdown in Php not giving the right values

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to make an inventory management system. This is my function to make dropdown for warehouse names and another one for Items names. When I select warehouse dropdown, I can see the inventory of that warehouse; however, when I select a particular product, I don't see anything.

Thanks a lot!!

```
function ViewWarehouseItems()
    {
?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <h2> View the Inventory</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Select a Warehouse Location</p>
    <script>
        function get_Items(value) 
                    {
                      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
                          {
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                          } 
                      else 
                          { 
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
                      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
                          {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
                                {
                                  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                                }
                          }
                      xmlhttp.open("GET","getitems.php?id="+value,true);
                      xmlhttp.send();
                    }                       
    </script>
    <form>
        <select name='warehouse_location' onchange="get_Items(this.value)">
        <option value='0'>..Select..</option>
    <?php 
    $sql="SELECT * from warehouses"; 
    $result=$this->connection_string->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $warehouse_id=$row['warehouse_id'];
            $warehouse_location=$row['warehouse_location'];
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $warehouse_id; ?>"><?php echo $warehouse_location; ?></option>
                            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <p>Select an Item</p>
    <form>
    <select name='item_name' onchange="get_Items(this.value)">
    <option value='0'>..Select an item..</option>
    <?php 
        $sql="SELECT * from items"; 
        $result=$this->connection_string->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $item_id=$row['item_id'];
            $item_name=$row['item_name'];
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>"><?php echo $item_name; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <?php echo "<br>"."<br>" ?>
    <div id="table"></div>
        <?php
}
```

And this is another php file which I am using in the function above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
echo $id;
include_once "dbConnect.php";
include_once "items.php";
include_once "warehouse.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE warehouse_id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
?>
        <div class="forum_header">
        <div class="item_topics_header">Warehouse ID</div>
        <div class="item_topics_header">Warehouse Location</div>
        <div class="item_topics_header">Item ID</div>
        <div class="item_topics_header">Item Name</div>
        <div class="item_topics_header">Inventory</div>
        </div>
<?php
$item_obj=new Items($conn);
$warehouse_obj=new Warehouse($conn);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $warehouse_id=$row['warehouse_id'];
            //$warehouse_location=$row['warehouse_location'];
            $wl=$warehouse_obj->GetWarehouseLocation($warehouse_id);
            $item_id=$row['item_id'];
            $i=$item_obj->GetItemName($item_id);
            //$item_name=$row['item_name'];
            $item_quantity=$row['item_quantity'];
            ?>
            <div class="forum_lines">
            <div class="item_replies_header"><?php echo $warehouse_id; ?></div>
            <div class="item_replies_header"><?php echo $wl; ?></div>
            <div class="item_replies_header"><?php echo $item_id; ?></div>
            <div class="item_replies_header"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
            <div class="item_replies_header"><?php echo $item_quantity; ?></div>
            </div>
    <?php
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
```

Comment: You might want to check if the select value is passed correctly. Sometimes you need to use 

    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value

Also add some error checking to the mysql query to see if it was executed correctly. What happens if you open getitems.php?id=1 directly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add some extra functionality to your getitems.php to check whether you are passing a warehouse or a product. So passing some sort of name would help you to determine which "type" of id is being passed.

Right now, you getitems.php presumes it's only a warehouse, and not anything further, based on your query.

Comment: In getItems.php, I did echo of $id and it is giving me the correct id for both warehouse and items. The only thing is that the values for items when selecting an item from the dropdown are not displaying. I think, there is some problem in my 'onchange' event for items dropdown. getItems.php should be fine because I am getting all the values from getItems.php when I select from warehouse dropdown.

Comment: But look at your query tho. It is basically saying: "SELECT whatever from items WHERE "warehouse_id" = something" But if you select an item, then it's not going to give you that item because the id selected IS NOT "warehouse_id" instead it's either "id" or "item_id" (or something like that)

Comment: So, what should I do. I m not sure.

Comment: As I stated, you need to pass more than just an id thru your ajax call, you could possible add it to your id being passed. Something like value="wh_{id}" and value="i_{id}" and then explode it in your php script and check for either wh or i for a type and then adjust your query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

So you'd do something like this:

```
<option value="i_<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
```

and

```
<option value="wh_<?php echo $warehouse_id; ?>">
```

Then modify your script to do the following:

```
$temp_id = explode("_", $_GET['id']);

$type = $temp_id[0];
$id = $temp_id[1];
```

and finally this:

```
if($type === 'wh'){

   $sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE warehouse_id = $id";

}
else if($type === "i"){
   $sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = $id";
  // MODIFY id to be the proper name for an item_id
}
```